# JPA EntityGraph making a Cartesian Product with subgraph

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I am working with Spring Data JPA and Entity Graphs.
I have the following Entity structure:
`Result` entity has a list of `SingleQuestionResponse` entities, and the `SingleQuestionResponse` entity has a set of `Answer` entities (markedAnswers).

```
public class Result {
...

 @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
 @JoinColumn(name = "result_id", nullable = false)
 private List<SingleQuestionResponse> responses;

...

}
```

```
public class SingleQuestionResponse {
...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
        name = "singlequestionresponses_answers",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "single_question_response_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
)
private Set<Answer> markedAnswers;

...
}
```

and `Answer` just has simple-type fields.

Now, I would like to be able to fetch Result, along with all responses, and the markedAnswers in one query. For that I annotated the `Result` class with:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.Result.responsesWithQuestionsAndAnswersEager",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "responses", subgraph = "responsesWithMarkedAnswersAndQuestion"),
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(name = "responsesWithMarkedAnswersAndQuestion", attributeNodes = {
                        @NamedAttributeNode("markedAnswers"),
                        @NamedAttributeNode("question")
                })
        }
)
```

an example of usage is:

```
@EntityGraph("graph.Result.responsesWithQuestionsAndAnswersEager")
List<Result> findResultsByResultSetId(Long resultSetId);
```

I noticed, that calling the `findResultsByResultSetId` method (and other methods using this entity graph) results in `responses` (`SingleQuestionResponse` entities) being multiplied by the number of `markedAnswers`. What I mean by that is that `result.getResponses()` returns more `SingleQuestionResponse` objects than it should (it returns one response object per each markedAnswer).

I realize this is due to Hibernate making a Cartesian product with the join, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Can you help please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DISTINCT` operator. With Spring Data JPA, this can be done by naming the method `findDistinctResultsByResultSetId`

Comment: I think that would distinct just root entity `Result` while OP issue regards the "middle" relationship, being `SingleQuestionResponse` collection stored in a `List`.
Is there any way to instruct Hibernate to deduplicate that one without turning collection in a `Set`?

Comment: Distinct is by default passed through to SQL so it will usually also deduplicate the elements in the list.

Comment: True. But hibernate will pass a `distinct` combining all selected columns, so every row will result different from the other ones. Tested copy/pasting produced query in mysql cli.  
Another proof of the fact that the "root distinction" happens in-memory, is that it generates exactly the same result if `HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` is passed.  
At the moment, result set generated by DB will always be cartesian product of all the three joined tables, and Hibernate in memory will deduplicate just the first one.

Comment: If multiple collections are join fetched, then yes, using distinct won't help. In that case you will have to use a `Set` everywhere or use `SELECT` or `SUBSELECT` fetching